# Why is there no contract for disposal?

Tags: c#, idisposable

We have constructors and we can treat them as contracts to follow for object instantiation.

There's no other way to create an instance without providing exact set of parameters to constructor.

But how can we (and should we ever bother) enforce some pre-mortem activity?
We've got the finalizer but they are not recommended for general purpose finalization.
We also have `IDisposable` to implement. But if we work with a disposable object without `using` we have no guarantee that Dispose will be ever called.

Why is there now way to enforce some state of the object before it will be let go off?

Tiding up in finalizer is impossible because there's no guarantee that object graph is intact and referenced object of dying object are not already nulled by GC.

Sure, not calling for instance object's `SaveState()` by the client code gives some troubles to it, not to my object.

Nonetheless it is considered to be a good practice to require all needed dependencies to be injected in constructor (if no default value is available). Nobody readily says: "leave default constructor, create properties and throw exceptions if object is in invalid state."

Update:

As there are many votes for closing the question I'd say that some design patterns for this can also be an answer.

Whether you use DI or not you can just count how many times object was requested/created. But without explicit release call you do not know the moment when you should call dispose.

I simply do not understand how to implement disposals at right time.

Comment: Such a contract would be impossible to enforce.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than a question.

Comment: Doing a full Disposable pattern (with finalizer as backup) is the closest you can get: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @spender pardon me =)

Comment: Incidentally, the object graph is guaranteed to be intact while `Finalize` methods are run.  What is not guaranteed is the sequence in which such methods will run.  It is possible for objects to coordinate finalization so that their resources are released in a particular sequence, if the objects are designed around such coordination.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is there no way to enforce some state of the object before it will be let go of?

Because the whole point of a garbage collector is to *[simulate a machine that has an infinite amount of memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx)*. If memory is infinite then you never need to clean it up.

You're conflating a *semantic requirement of your program* -- that a particular side effect occur at a particular time -- with *the mechanisms of simulating infinite storage*. In an ideal world those two things should not have anything to do with each other. Unfortunately we do not live in an ideal world; the existence of finalizers is evidence of that.

If there are effects that you want to achieve at a particular time, then *those effects are part of your program* and you should *write code that achieves them*. If they are important then they should be *visible in the code* so that people reading the code can see and understand them.

Comment: The fact that an object might need to ask other entities to do things on its behalf--to the detriment of other entities--until it knows it will no longer be asked to do anything is hardly an unexpected implementation detail.  The particulars of who the other entities are and what is asked of them are implementation details, but the fact that an object might have asked other entities to act on its behalf should in many cases be *expected*.  Such semantics are required frequently, and should have nothing to do with garbage collection.  Alas, few languages seem to take the issue seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, during the design of Java, it was anticipated that the garbage collector should be able to satisfy all cleanup requirements. That seems to have been a belief during early design stages of .NET as well.

Consequently, no distinction is made between:

- an `object reference` which encapsulates exclusive ownership of its target;
- a `reference to an object` which *does not* encapsulate ownership(its target is owned by someone else);
- a `reference whose owner` knows that it will either *encapsulate exclusive ownership* or *encapsulate none*, and knows which case applies for the instance at hand;
- or an `object reference` which encapsulates shared ownership.

If a language and framework were properly designed around such distinctions, it would seldom be necessary to write code where proper cleanup could not be statically verified (the first two cases, which probably apply 90%+ of the time, could easily be statically verified even with the .NET framework).

Unfortunately, because no such distinctions exist outside the very limited context of `using` statements, there's no way for a compiler or verifier to know, when a piece of code abandons a reference, whether anything else is expecting to clean up the object referred to thereby.

Consequently, **there's no way** to know in general whether the object **should** be disposed, and no generally-meaningful way to squawk if it should be but isn't.